# Debugging object in isml

Tags: commerce-cloud

Is it possible to dump the entire contents of a var in an isml template.

For example this gives me output:

```
${payment.paymentMethod}
```

But if I want to debug the entire 'payment' object:

```
${payment}
```

The result is: [object Object]

Answer (score 10):

You can use as below in script:

```
<isscript>
    out.print( JSON.stringify(payment) );
</isscript>
```

This will stringify the object and show string as below:

> "{"paymentName":"name_value","paymentMethod":"method_name"}"

instead of [object Object]

Comment: thanks that works. I also discovered that for more detailed debugging I can use the debugger tool in VS Code to create break points to see the value of all objects